# How to prevent requestAnimationFrame choppiness whilst lazy loading images?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, lazy-loading, web-worker, requestanimationframe

To paint the story:

I have some visual content which is divided into sets of images (tiles).

I'm using a simple loop which gets invoked by `requestAnimationFrame` to display these tiles on a canvas.

Actually I'm using PixiJS for this stuff; though it's probably an implementation detail not quite relevant to this question.

Because there might be a lot of tiles and because I would like the user to be able to 'somewhat immediately' scroll through these sets of tiles I'm preloading only a certain set of tiles, then when the user further navigates the tileset, another stream of tiles gets loaded, until there are no more tiles to load.

When the visual content is completely loaded the `requestAnimationFrame` looop functions well, without any choppiness.

But during the lazy loading there is some choppiness now and then.

I've tried using `setInterval` to separate the lazy loading (and the waste management or garbage collection too) from the `requestAnimationFrame` loop.

But I later realized this is because JavaScript only has one thread and thus the loading of images is blocking the rest of the code. So `setInterval` is not helpful; nor would be a second `requestAnimatonFrame` invocation for the lazy loading.

Then I read about Web Workers which does set up a possibility for concurrent execution of things. But as I read all data in a Web Worker thread is copied instead of passed by reference. So it would take up double the memory.

And also I'm doubting a Web Worker will be a suitable feature for loading tiles concurrently because the Mozilla Developer Network pages mostly appoint it as a help for parallel (heavy) number crunching solution.

There is a specific Web Worker type; a Service Worker which sits between the web page requests and the web server. Would a Service Worker help me at all loading images whilst executing the paint loop?

If not, does some one know of an alternate way to still lazy load but also animate the already loaded set of images? Is there something obvious I have overlooked?

**Edit 3:** Please look closely; the stutter is there while images load; sometimes more than other times; but it is still there; since I was instructed as per the comment section to remove my simulation it is much less obvious; but the stutter is still there. It's easier to see if one expands the snippet and then after opening up Developer Console, going to Network tab and checking "Disable cache", click the Run-button.

**Edit 2:** Ignore edit 1. Because the simulation has been replaced by real images loading now. The stutter is noticeable when loading the images the first time or when browser cache has been turned off.

**Edit 1:** As requested an example. The lazy load blockage is simulated by looping until a certain random delay has executed. The colors are supposed to represent the tile images but are actually drawn from a canvas using a random color.

```js
var tileImageURLs = [
  "https://i.postimg.cc/FdFCY0RL/tile1.png",
  "https://i.postimg.cc/v1tS80Qy/tile2.png",
  "https://i.postimg.cc/3yTcHsQ9/tile3.png",
  "https://i.postimg.cc/Hr5hRpRV/tile4.png",
  "https://i.postimg.cc/fJ1P83HG/tile5.png",
  "https://i.postimg.cc/LnJ7kkVk/tile6.png",
];

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var y = 0;
var NORMALSPEED = 5;
var currentSpeed = NORMALSPEED;
var TILEWIDTH = 768;
var TILEHEIGHT = 1024;
var TILECOUNT = 6;
var tileImages = [];
var lastTileLoad = -1;
var tileLoadStart = 0;
var PRELOADEDTILESCOUNT = 2;

// For offscreen generation of tiles.
//var tileCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
//tileCanvas.width = TILEWIDTH;
//tileCanvas.height = TILEHEIGHT;
//var tileCtx = tileCanvas.getContext('2d');
//var tileColors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'orange', 'yellow'];

for (var tileIdx = 0; tileIdx < TILECOUNT; tileIdx++) {
  tileImages[tileIdx] = document.createElement('img');
  tileImages[tileIdx].width = TILEWIDTH;
  tileImages[tileIdx].height = TILEHEIGHT;
}


function loadTileImages(tileStart, tileEnd) {
  if (tileImages[tileStart]) {
    tileImages[tileStart].onload = function() {
      // Image loaded; go to next tile if applicable.
      if (tileStart + 1 <= tileEnd) {
        loadTileImages(++tileStart, tileEnd);
      }
    }
    tileImages[tileStart].src = tileImageURLs[tileStart];
  }
}

function loadTiles() {
  var tileLoadCount;
  if (lastTileLoad < Math.round(y / (canvas.height * 1))) {
    /**
     * Load checkpoint which lies past previous load checkpoint found;
     * so load some stuff.
     */
    tileLoadCount = Math.min(tileLoadStart + PRELOADEDTILESCOUNT - 1, TILECOUNT);
    loadTileImages(tileLoadStart, tileLoadCount);

    tileLoadStart += PRELOADEDTILESCOUNT;


    if (tileLoadStart > TILECOUNT - 1) {
      /**
       * Stop the loading; Infinity is always bigger than a non-infinite number.
       */
      console.log('Loading has finished.');
      lastTileLoad = Infinity;
    } else {
      /**
       * Store this 'load checkpoint'.
       */
      //this.needToDrawFrame = true;
      lastTileLoad = Math.round(y / (canvas.height * 1));
    }
  }
}

function tick() {
  var tileImgY;
  if (currentSpeed > 0 && (y >= (TILECOUNT * TILEHEIGHT) - canvas.height)) {
    currentSpeed = -NORMALSPEED;
  } else if (currentSpeed < 0 && (y <= 0)) {
    currentSpeed = NORMALSPEED;
  }
  y += currentSpeed;

  loadTiles();

  var tileStart = Math.max(Math.floor(y / TILEHEIGHT) - 1, 0);
  var tileCount = Math.min(tileStart + Math.ceil(canvas.height / TILEHEIGHT) + 2, TILECOUNT);
  //console.log(y, tileStart, tileCount);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  for (var tileIndex = tileStart; tileIndex < tileCount; tileIndex++) {
    var tileImg = tileImages[tileIndex];
    tileImgY = (tileIndex * TILEHEIGHT) - y;
    ctx.drawImage(tileImg, 0, tileImgY, TILEWIDTH, TILEHEIGHT);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(tick);
}

requestAnimationFrame(tick);
```

```css
#canvas {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="768" height="1024"></canvas>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "choppiness"? Can you demonstrate the issue at stacknsippets? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/.  A dedicated `Worker` or `SharedWorker`  thread can make requests and post or transfer data to the main thread.  It is not clear what the issue is or how using a `ServiceWorker`, as opposed to a `Worker`, or not using a `Worker` at all is related to solving the issue of image "choppiness".

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The "choppiness" is about the loading of remote files (images) blocking the paint loop (requestAnimationFrame) whilst loading. When the paint loop is waiting for the images to load there can be no new paint; which thus results in "scroll jank" or "choppiness". Because a few frames are skipped during the scrolling because time has passed since the load blockage. Does this make the problem clearer? I can try and make a pasty.

Comment: I have added a code snippet.

Comment: Your problem might be caused by the fact that images will be decoded in the same thread that runs your code and paints.

Comment: I've replaced img.onLoad with img.decode().then(() => { // load function }) and moved the img.src-line but I still experience the same issue. Should apart from the image decoding process the image downloading itself not also block the main thread? Thanks though.

Comment: You might still be right DoMiNeLa10. I read this thread here: https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/issues/4611 I'm going to see if I can use a web worker to invoke createImageBitmap. Maybe that will cause image decoding to take place in a background thread.

Comment: I used the web-worker-blob-method using this repository: https://github.com/m9dfukc/createImageBitmap-performance but the issue is regretfully still there.

Comment: Why is a `while` loop being used to "simulate"  a "random delay"? Why is any simulation needed? Why is `setInteval` being used where `requestAnimationFrame` can be used? What is the purpose of the recursive call to `loadTileImages`?

Comment: @Wieger Removing `var t0 = performance.now();
    var t1 = performance.now();
    // Simulates loading of a tile with a random delay (max. 100 ms in example);
    var randomDelay = Math.random() * 100;
    while(t1 - t0 < randomDelay) {
      t1 = performance.now();
    }` removes the "choppiness".

Comment: I have removed the simulation and replaced it with a more realistic scenario: loading some images from a server. If you look closely stutter does occur.

Comment: A reason for writing the simulation was to prevent "link rot" (linked images who will some day disappear). But maybe we've got to live on the edge these days.

Comment: I've put the loading of images in the same rAF now by the way too. Because it does not really seem to matter if I use a separate setInterval or a separate requestAnimationFrame for the loading of the tiles.

Comment: The purpose of the recursive call to `loadTileImages` is to load tiles one by one, in the correct load order. Maybe one can load up to say 6 tiles concurrently when using Chrome but I suspect that if a server handles one image to load, it would be quicker with that one image and possibly slower loading the first tiles when loading e.g. 6 tiles concurrently; e.g. total would be quicker but tile 1 could be later to load than tile 6 for instance. That's what I figured.

Comment: @Wieger Not sure what the issue is at the code at updated question? Is the question hypothetical?

Comment: The question is not hypothetical. It's real. If you look close enough their is some micro-stutter. Just make sure to disable cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an answer to my own question; it was mostly stupidity on my end.

As it turns out it was making extra calls to the ticker function (invoked by `requestAnimationFrame`) during the loading phase (meant to make sure screen refreshed when new tile images arrived).

These calls caused spurts of extra movement and made it feel like there was some stutter (more heavy than I was able to reproduce in my example by the way).

But part of the stutter - the micro-stutter - went away after I used `createImageBitmap` in a Web Worker to load the images.